# Such that in set-builder notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I want to define a set $A=\{x:\exists y\ni P(x,y)\}$. That is, $A$ is the set of all $x$ such that there exists a $y$ such that $P(x,y)$ holds. Is using $\ni$ fine, or should I write $A=\{x:\exists y:P(x,y)\}$ or $A=\{x:\exists y, P(x,y)\}$? Thanks.

Comment: I would say it this way:
$$A=\{x:P(x,y)\;\text{for some}\;y\}$$
For the cost of two words, you gain clarity.

Comment: But of your posted options, I like the last one 
$$A=\{x:\exists y, P(x,y)\}$$
best.

Comment: While $\ni$ has been traditionally used for “such that”, that usage is not common anymore and it is easily confused with reverse containment, i.e. $A \ni x$ meaning the same as $x \in A$. So I would go with your last option or with words as in @quasi’s comment.